# Trying to Animate a group of lines

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making a pattern similar to this...

[image: Hexagon Pattern]

By kicking off a story board per a line array and performing the calculations. Although, I'm having trouble nailing down how to kick off multiple line animations at the same time.

Here's what i've tried so far:

```
Canvas canMain = new Canvas();
canMain.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
canMain.Margin = new Thickness(50, 0, 0, 0);
Line[] line = new Line[6];
Storyboard sb;
DoubleAnimation da, da1;
for (int i = 0; i < line.Count(); i++)
{
    line[i].Stroke = Brushes.Red;
    line[i].StrokeThickness = 1;
    line[i].X1 = i+11;
    line[i].Y1 = i+11;
    canMain.Children.Add(line[i]);
    sb = new Storyboard();
    da = new DoubleAnimation(line[i].Y1, 30, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)));
    da1 = new DoubleAnimation(line[i].X1, 30, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)));
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath("(Line.Y2)"));
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da1, new PropertyPath("(Line.X2)"));
    sb.Children.Add(da);
    sb.Children.Add(da1);
    line[i].BeginStoryboard(sb);
}
```

As you can tell I haven't began to do the math behind it because I can't seem to trigger the storyboards all at the same time. Or should I be stashing all the `doubleAnimations` into the same storyboard? Both of these approaches gets me a stackoverflow. I am relatively new to WPF C# programming, so any advice or further information would be extremely helpful.

Editing post to include Exceptions:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: *I can't seem to trigger the storyboards all at the same time*... what does that code do then?

Comment: Causes the program to crash.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question and add the `Exception` details? Also, you should only use the minimum number of lines to create your pattern... you can use a `VisualBrush` to tile the pattern across a larger area far cheaper than drawing them all.

Comment: I am away from my office PC until tomorrow, so I apologize I cannot post the exception at the moment. Thank you for the suggestion on the visual brush, is there any link references that can get me properly informed on how to use that method for larger area animation and drawing?

Comment: How about the [`VisualBrush` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN?

Comment: Thanks @Sheridan, I've added in my Exceptions.

Comment: Sorry, that's no good... whenever you see a `TargetInvocationException`, you need to look into the *inner* `Exception`.

Comment: @Sheridan Inner Exception is `null` try{}catch{} results.

Comment: @Sheridan Thanks for trying to help, i'll wait until tomorrow and post a bounty so i can get more eyes on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is mostly fine.  I only had to make a minor change to get it working.  I created a new window called `new_Window` to test in and created a `Canvas` object on it called `canMain`.
Then I just added one line of code to yours:  Inside your `for` loop I had to add `line[i] = new Line();` because the line objects were null at that point.

```
  public new_Window()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     AnimateThis();
  }

  private void AnimateThis()
  {
     canMain.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
     canMain.Margin = new Thickness(50, 0, 0, 0);
     Line[] line = new Line[6];
     Storyboard sb;
     DoubleAnimation da, da1;
     for (int i = 0; i < line.Count(); i++)
     {
        line[i] = new Line();
        line[i].Stroke = Brushes.Red;
        line[i].StrokeThickness = 1;
        line[i].X1 = i+11;
        line[i].Y1 = i+11;
        canMain.Children.Add(line[i]);
        sb = new Storyboard();
        da = new DoubleAnimation(line[i].Y1, 30, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)));
        da1 = new DoubleAnimation(line[i].X1, 30, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)));
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath("(Line.Y2)"));
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da1, new PropertyPath("(Line.X2)"));
        sb.Children.Add(da);
        sb.Children.Add(da1);
        line[i].BeginStoryboard(sb);
     }
  }
```

I added the `Canvas` to the window first because I wanted to make sure that there was a surface ready to be rendered on.